# How is the size changes from 6 to 2 in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Try to run it by yourself if it gives the expected output i.e. `Length: 5` then tell me what the problem is and if it gives the same output as mine then tell the me the mistake which I've made in my code...

and run this program without those 2 lines which I've mentioned in the code you'll have the expected output.

Code:

```
fun  main(args: Array<String>) {
var list1: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5)
list1.add(6)
println("Length: ${list1.size}")

// Problem is in these 2 lines

var list3 = list1.subList(0,3)              // Line no. 1

list3.clear()                               // Line no. 3

list1.remove(5)

println("Length: ${list1.size}")

list1.forEach{n -> println(n)}
}
```

and this is the Output:

```
Length: 6
List 3: 1
List 3: 2
List 3: 3

Length: 2
4
6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `subList`:

> **Returns a view of the portion of this list** between the specified fromIndex (inclusive) and toIndex (exclusive). The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html

`List3` is not a new list, it's a view of the original list. Once you clear it, the elements get also removed from the original.

Compare:

```
var list3 = list1.subList(0,3).toMutableList()
```

Although the behavior for structural changes in the view is not defined, the only way it can work is through copying of changes to the base list - you cannot clear a view without clearing that part of the base list.

Comment: Those docs should really say something about structural changes to the view. They only mention non-structural changes and structural changes to the base list.

Comment: @user2357112 Very true. Technically, the behavior is undefined and that's not something I would expect in a modern language. However, logically - structural changes in the base list make the view invalid and structural changes in the view get copied to the base list.